# Can I have XML Defination in this way

Tags: c#

HI

Can i have a xml defination like below

```
<add key="FirstName" ServerType="FirstName" Mandatory="Yes" length="3" DataType="String"/>
```

if yes how can i read this in my dot net c# code i use dotnet 2.0 frame work
Please help me with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean can you use such an element to your `appSettings` configuration section, then the answer is no. The `add` element can only have single `key` and `value` attributes.

Comment: Thanks oded...
Basically i can have a seperate xml file also in defining this...
Can i do this if i have a seperate xml file and how

Comment: You will have to write your own parsing of the XML.